# figure out how to get the last enddate of a bi-weekly week

Tags: java, calendar

Okay got my head spinning from reviewing a bunch of other code but now i gotta tackle something that seems easy but i can't figure it out.

I need to update a function that currently gets today's date, checks if it is NOT Saturday if it is not then we go ahead and make java cal to Saturday and then add -7 days to it. This function allows us to get the last day of a pay period but now we are going to go bi-weekly so now I need to update the code to check the date and if it is greater then last weekly date of pay which was the 7/17th (7/11/2021 - 7/17/2021). Our first bi-weekly pay is 7/18 - 7/31 so any of these days need to look for the last endate to be 7/17 then all other bi-weekly need to look at the end dates of the other bi-weekly. So I need to figure out the logic that would figure out how much it will add -x to the week. My thought is add -7 to the first week of the bi weekly and -14 or the second week of the bi weekly. Trying to avoid having to do drastic updates throughout the code.

```
public Calendar getLastEndDate() {
     Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
     if(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)!=Calendar.SATURDAY){
         cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SATURDAY);
         cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -7);
     }
     
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);
return cal;}
```

Comment: What if today's date is 10th Jul 2021, do you still subtract 7 from it?

Comment: Tip: [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library, and its [`org.threeten.extra.LocalDateRange`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html) class.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Is your week always from Sunday to Saturday, or could users in a different locale see that differently? How am I supposed to know which weeks make up a biweekly period? I mean, AFAIAC it could be 7/18–7/31 or it could be 7/25–8/7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you will have to check the week numbers.
If you are always doing payout on even weeks the following code would work.

Test code included.

```java
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import static java.util.Calendar.*;

public class BiWeekly {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
            cal.set(DATE, i);
            System.out.print("Today is: " + df.format(cal.getTime()));
            System.out.print(", Week: " + cal.get(WEEK_OF_YEAR));
            BiWeekly bw = new BiWeekly();
            System.out.println(", Last payout was: " + df.format(bw.getLastEndDate(cal).getTime()));
        }
    }

    public Calendar getLastEndDate(Calendar orig) {
        Calendar cal = new Calendar.Builder().setInstant(orig.getTime()).build();
        int week = cal.get(WEEK_OF_YEAR);
        if (week % 2 == 0) {
            cal.add(DATE, -7);
        }
        else {
            cal.add(DATE, -14);
        }
        cal.set(DAY_OF_WEEK, SATURDAY);

        cal.set(HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        cal.set(MINUTE, 0);
        cal.set(SECOND, 0);
        cal.set(MILLISECOND, 0);
        return cal;
    }
}
```

Comment: The terrible `Calendar` class was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 2):

I could be wrong so feel free to correct me and i'll make adjustments. After looking at the requirements, what it seems you really want to do is get the duration between now and the next pay date. To do that, you need to know the next pay date.

To calculate the pay date we can use the initial date you indicated and continue for N days/weeks until the current date is before the end date for the pay period.

That way we know that the start of the pay period is `endDate - cycle` and the duration until the pay date is `endDate - currentDate`.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate firstPayDate = LocalDate.of(2021, 7, 18);

        LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();

        Period payCycle = Period.ofWeeks(2);

        LocalDate nextPayDate = nextPayDate(firstPayDate, payCycle, currentDate);

        Period periodUntilPayDate = Period.between(currentDate, nextPayDate);

        System.out.printf("Next pay date is in %d days on %s.",
                periodUntilPayDate.getDays(),
                nextPayDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE));
    }

    private static LocalDate nextPayDate(LocalDate payDate, Period payCycle, LocalDate currentDate) {
        while (currentDate.isAfter(payDate)) {
            payDate = payDate.plus(payCycle);

            if (currentDate.isBefore(payDate)) {
                return payDate;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("Could not find pay period.");
    }
```

> Next pay date is in 9 days on 2021-08-01.

Also, this is kind of out of scope but if you wanted to cover a few bases you could validate input.

```java
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(payDate);
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(payCycle);
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(currentDate);
        Preconditions.checkArgument(!payCycle.isNegative());
        Preconditions.checkArgument(!payCycle.isZero());
```